# unable to find package when apt install

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, apt, dlib

I failed to find the package when I want to install libdlib-dev.I have run `apt update` and I also change the server.Both of them don't work.My system is ubuntu 14.04.

[apt failed info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGei2.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The package `libdlib-dev` isn't available for Ubutnu 14.04.It is only available for  xenial, artful, bionic and cosmic.

see [Package: libdlib-dev](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libdlib-dev)

Answer (score -1):

Welcome to stackoverflow David

Usually adding the respective repository before installation helps solve the issue
Try finding the repo and use the commands below

sudo add-apt-repository repo-name

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt install package-name

if not, you can go through this link http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu-fix-broken-package-best-solution/ , might help you fix the issue.
Feel free to ask if any clarification needed

Comment: When I run 
sudo add-apt-repository 
it shows 'need a repository as argument'

Comment: edited my solution, u need to find the correct repo to the corresponding package that you need to install, use this as an example https://thishosting.rocks/install-java-ubuntu/

Comment: I want to install libdlib-dev,a repository of c，not java.Thank you, but the answer is not what I want.